# Laravel - Recreate custom request with validation on the fly

Tags: laravel

I need to be able to recreate an `$request` variable, reach the validation of that request, and also beeing able to access route params (/foo/{user_id}) and query params (/foo?user_id), like this example.

Note! This is an silly example, i know that this specific problem can be resolved in a much simpler way, but my current enviriment is too complexi to explain, also it would be unnecessary

```
class RandomController {

    // /foo/{field1}?field2
    public function create(CreateRequest $request) {
        if ($request->has('id') {
            $new_request = recreateRequest($request->only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')); // field3 is on the body
            return $this->update($new_request);
        }
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request) {
        $request->field1; // /foo/{field1}
        $request->field2; // /foo?field2
        $request->field3; // {field3: }
    }

}
```

Now I recreate the request passing it as an prop (CustomRequest::class) and using this following code, but it is unstable, sometimes it doesn't reach the request properties and I have to write `$request->request->field1` instead of `$request->field1`

```
$created_request = new $new_request(
    $query ?: $old_request->query->all(),
    $request ?: $old_request->request->all(),
    $attributes ?: $old_request->attributes->all(),
    $cookies ?: $old_request->cookies->all(),
    $files ?: $old_request->files->all(),
    $server ?: $old_request->server->all()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own request object by artisan using the following command:

```
php artisan make:request RequestName
```

this should create a request file in your HTTP request folder and you can still use the global request variable `$request` so you can access all the parameters and use the validation.

and then just import it using

use Illuminate\Http\YourCustomRequest;

and replace the controller method argument with the new request you just imported like so

```
public function create(YourCustomRequest $myRequest) {
    //do some action.
}
```

check the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but sorry if my question wasn't clear, I already have an custom request, as you can see as a parameter to each method, my problem is when trying to custom creating a request object and not an request class